# Lucene deletable files are locked

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

I use to reindex MassIndexer. I got example of code from some site(can't remember where).

```
massIndexe.purgeAllOnStart(true) // true by default, highly recommended
.optimizeAfterPurge(true) // true is default, saves some disk space
.optimizeOnFinish(true) // true by default
.batchSizeToLoadObjects(100)
.threadsForSubsequentFetching(15)
.threadsToLoadObjects(10)
.limitIndexedObjectsTo(1000)
.cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE) // defaults to CacheMode.IGNORE
.startAndWait();
```

But after several reindex size of index really really huge. any suggestion how I can resolve this.

Lucene say :

> This is normal behavior on Windows
>   whenever you also have readers
>   (IndexReaders or IndexSearchers) open
>   against the index you are optimizing.
>   Lucene tries to remove old segments
>   files once they have been merged
>   (optimized). However, because Windows
>   does not allow removing files that are
>   open for reading, Lucene catches an
>   IOException deleting these files and
>   and then records these pending
>   deletable files into the "deletable"
>   file. On the next segments merge,
>   which happens with explicit optimize()
>   or close() calls and also whenever the
>   IndexWriter flushes its internal
>   RAMDirectory to disk (every
>   IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFERED_DOCS
>   (default 10) addDocuments), Lucene
>   will try again to delete these files
>   (and additional ones) and any that
>   still fail will be rewritten to the
>   deletable file.

but I believe that have some way ti resolve this. In any case index will take all free space because in any time it in use by someone..